# Docker issue with public IP

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm building my node application using

```
docker build -t myrepo/myapp .
```

later I'm running using this command

```
docker run -d --name myapp -p 8000:8000 -t myrepo/myapp
```

now I'm checking my doing this

```
docker ps -a
```

I'm getting output like this

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                    NAMES
7fa5bbaebc0b        myrepo/myapp      "supervisord -c /e..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds             0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   myapp
```

and later I'm accessing the app using public ip like this PUBLIC_IP:8000 but nothing comes up

`Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf", "-n"]
```

my curl output on remote server:

```
curl -v 0.0.0.0:8000 
* Rebuilt URL to: 0.0.0.0:8000/ 
* Trying 0.0.0.0... 
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0) > GET / HTTP/1.1 > Host: 0.0.0.0:8000 > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0 > Accept: */* > 
* Empty reply from server 
* Connection #0 to host 0.0.0.0 left intact curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

`supervisord.conf`

```
[program:myapp]
command=node index.js
directory=/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=NODE_ENV=production
stderr_logfile=/var/log/atlas.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/atlas.out.log
```

Comment: Once again whats the issue?

Comment: what do you mean by nothing comes up? server timeout ?

Comment: No I can run the app using node start app.js but unable to start app using docker. I'm getting message like This site can’t be reached

Comment: @VaibhavKadam while asking a question try to add as much usefull information as possible. The next is logs file ? did you check them. Also for the sake of others please attach both the supervisor and docker logs on question

Comment: sorry sir. I'l add log file ad docker in question @georoot

Comment: I guess Your node app are visible on port 3000 and You try to expose port 8000. Check them.

Comment: There's not enough to go by in this question. All we know is that you run a node command, not if that command is listening on any port, and if so, what port? We'd need logfiles of the containers. Lastly, the curl command should be to the docker host IP, not the listener 0.0.0.0 pseudo address.

Answer (score 0):

Your app are listening on `127.0.0.1:8000`. Change your app configuration to listening on `0.0.0.0:8000`.

More info on [docker issue 2522](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2522)